# Replace only last occurrence of a string using perl command

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a stdout or a file does not matter:

```
mela
pera
banana
caffè
mela
pera
banana
caffè
mela
pera
banana
caffè
```

I want remove only last occurrence of "`mela`" using `perl`:

```
mela
pera
banana
caffè
mela
pera
banana
caffè
pera
banana
caffè
```

how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lwne '
    if ($_ eq "mela") {
        if ($i) {
            print for splice @buffer, 0, $i;
        }
        $i = 1+$#buffer;
    }
    push @buffer, $_;
    END {
        splice @buffer, $i, 1;
        print for @buffer;
    }'
```

`-n` reads the input (file or stdin) line by line. Instead of printing each line, you push the lines into a buffer. When you encounter `mela`, you make `$i` to point to its position in the buffer. When you encounter `mela` again, you print the first part of the buffer up to the previous `mela`. At the end of the input, you print the buffer *except* for the last `mela` which is being pointed to by `$i`.

Not tested for edge cases (several `mela`s following each other, `mela` on the first/last line, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In a standalone Perl progam:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Desc: Repeat everything back, except last occurrence of given string
# Synt: $0 string <infile

## for each input record in reverse order,
##   if string not found before, and found now, set flag, else stack record
## print stack
$s = shift."\n";   # get string, append LF
for ( reverse <STDIN> ) {
    if ( !$f && $s eq $_ )  { $f=1          }
    else                    { unshift @o,$_ }
}
print @o;
```

OR as a one-liner for advanced users, in action:

```
$ echo -e "11\nmela\n22\nmela\n33" | perl -e '$s=shift."\n";
 !$f && $s eq $_ ? $f=1 : unshift @o,$_  for reverse <STDIN>;
 print @o;' mela
11
mela
22
33
```